# Symfony: Make a datetime form field really read-only

Tags: php, symfony, twig, fieldtype

I marked a datetime form field as read_only. Since this seams to have no effect I overruled the default twig template. This works fine.

```
{% block datetime_widget %}
    {% if read_only %}
        {{ value.date.year }}-{{ value.date.month }}-{{ value.date.day }} {{ value.time.hour }}:{{ value.time.minute }}
    {% else %}
        {{ parent() }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

This is the form type I'm using:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
abstract class BusinessClass
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

}
```

And this is how the datetime field is added to the form builder:

```
$formBuilder->add('created', 'datetime', array('read_only' => true));
```

However, symfony still tries to set the unchanged value back to my form type. Since it's read-only I only implemented a get method but not set method. That's why I get this error message:

```
InvalidPropertyException: Neither element "created" nor method "setCreated()" exists in class "Cinergy\ShopBundle\Tests\Functional\TestBundle\Entity\RecurringProduct"

    in /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Util/PropertyPath.php line 552
    at PropertyPath->writeProperty(object(RecurringProduct), 'created', null, false, null) in /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Util/PropertyPath.php line 318
    at PropertyPath->setValue(object(RecurringProduct), null) in /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataMapper/PropertyPathMapper.php line 74
    at PropertyPathMapper->mapFormsToData(array('created' => object(Form), 'duration' => object(Form), 'id' => object(Form), 'name' => object(Form), 'price' => object(Form), 'sku' => object(Form), 'updated' => object(Form), '__entity' => object(Form), '__id' => object(Form)), object(RecurringProduct)) in /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 569
    at Form->bind(object(Request)) in /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/src/Cinergy/DaylightBundle/Controller/BrowserController.php line 123
    at BrowserController->updateAction(object(Request))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(BrowserController), 'updateAction'), array(object(Request))) in /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/src/Cinergy/CommonBundle/EventListener/TransactionWrapper.php line 34
    at TransactionWrapper->wrappedExecution(object(Request))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(TransactionWrapper), 'wrappedExecution'), array(object(Request))) in /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 1426
    at HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1') in /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 1390
    at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 1566
    at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 617
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in /Users/ernst/Source/php/cinergy/shop/web/app_dev.php line 28
```

Since this is part of my business logic I don't want to implement a setCreate method. It's also woth mentioning, that the very same thing works fine for text fields.

Any ideas about how I can stop symfony from setting the value if the `read_only` option is set?

Comment: you want to set `mapped` to false if its just for show. If I understand you correctly. Otherwise, post some code (more so than just the twig snippet)

Comment: Setting mapped to false does to much, it stopy symfony from reading the value as well.

Comment: Added the form tyoe and the form builder handling. Please not that the very same thing works fine for text fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: Use `disabled` instead of `read_only`.

After finding the [relevant part in the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#read-only) I think that the rendering of datetime for `read_only` is not correct. Only setting `read_only` is changing nothing. According to the docs it should be rednered as read only HTML.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, if a mapped field is set to be disabled it is then not persisted.  Its value becomes null, which is probably not what the OP is looking for.  An alternate solution is to do something like the following in your template:

```
{% if household.dateAdded is not null %}{{ household.dateAdded|date('m/d/Y') }}
<input type="hidden" name="household[dateAdded]" value="{{ household.dateAdded|date('m/d/Y') }}">
{% endif %}
```

where household is the form name, dateAdded is the mapped field name.

Comment: This is potentially dangerous, you are making the field appear read only, but in fact a knowledgeable user can change the value of the hidden field, save the form and therefore change data that you didn't want them to. You should never accept data from a user unless you trust them to provide that data.

Comment: @thelem I'll accept that a knowledgeable user could change the value in a hidden field.  The application where the answer appears is behind a firewall for a small non-profit organization whose users are well short of knowledgeable in this regard.  Do you have an alternate solution?

Comment: From reading the docs I think disabled should work as you want it to (as described in the other answer). A field that has a value in the database, that is marked as disabled, should not lose that value when the form is saved. For my use case I'm currently passing the information to the form separately, so the form never processes that field.

Comment: @thelem It is unfortunately not true that a form's disabled field will be persisted to an entity.  This can be confirmed by observing a field's value before and after submitting a form with a disabled field (e.g., `{{ form_row(form.housing, {'attr': {'disabled': 'disabled'}}) }}`.  Under this condition the field is set to null.  Perhaps you could present your method of "passing the information to the form separately" as an answer?

Comment: @thelem I did post [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35965065/cannot-both-disable-entity-field-and-retain-its-value) some time ago to my similar question that allows for disabled fields to be persisted without the risk of a hidden field.