# Symfony date form field won't take read_only attribute

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to get a Symfony Form date field to be read only. The syntax work for a text field but not for a date-select field.

This is the problem line:

```
->add('CreationDate', 'date', array('read_only' => true))
```

This is the full function:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $a=1;
    $builder
            ->add('Instructor_Lic','text',array('read_only' => true))
            ->add('First_Name')
            ->add('Last_Name')
            ->add('School_ID')
            ->add('Email')
            ->add('Status')
            ->add('Department')
            ->add('CreationDate', 'date', array('read_only' => true))
            ->add('EditDate', 'date', array('data' => new \DateTime()))
    ;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can use `disabled` attribute  instead of `disabled` like this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437802/symfony-make-a-datetime-form-field-really-read-only

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. Works. Submit as answer for the credit.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct method to do it.

```
->add('CreationDate', 'date', array(
    'disabled' => true
)
```

Also, on newer symfony versions, instead of using form alias 'date', use:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
// ...

$builder->add('CreationDate', DateType::class, array(
    'disabled' => true,
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `disabled` attribute instead of `read_only` attribute

**change**

```
->add('CreationDate', 'date', array('read_only' => true))
```

**to**

```
->add('CreationDate', 'date', array('disabled' => true))
```

[like accepted answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437802/symfony-make-a-datetime-form-field-really-read-only)