# Cannot both disable entity field and retain its value

Tags: php, symfony

In a form event, setting a field `'attr' => array('readonly' => 'readonly')` is rendered as `"disabled" = "1"`.  This is not the desired effect. A disabled select field persists a null value on submit.  A readonly field should retain and persist the displayed value.  Or so I thought.  So how to get the value to remain unchanged and unchangeable?

Edit;

A hidden field does not do the trick.  `choice_attr` does not help either.

I'm voting to close this question.  I've not discovered any method for displaying a disabled entity field and also retain the value. If you've got any idea on how that's done...

An example (in Symfony 2.8.3):
The Household entity has six attributes, each of which is an entity in a OneToMany relationship to Household.  (The application has other entities which have similar attributes.) The Housing entity/attribute of Household has two properties: housing and enabled. The application's client can set a property to `enabled = no` if they no longer intend to track that property.

If a property is set to `enabled = no` its availability in a new or edit Household form is readily eliminated by including a where clause in the entity field's query builder, e.g., `->where("h.enabled=1")`.  However, doing so causes the disabled property to be set to `null`. Thus the need for retaining the value somehow.

The ideal solution would be a service for these attribute entity fields that would both display values and retain if enabled is no.

I have tried using an event listener, a hidden field, `choice_attr`, modifying the form template and the form theme all to no avail. For example, a hidden field is text when an entity field is required. This doesn't mean it can't be done, only that I haven't stumbled on the proper method.

Comment: You could display the information in a span or div or anything but an input/select element and have a hidden input with the actual value. Not a pretty solution though.

Comment: And even less fun in a form event.  I've not tried a hidden field with an entity field before, either.

Comment: Has `readonly` been removed as an allowable attribute?

Comment: I am not a symfony2 user but a quick Google shows a `read_only` attribute. Maybe you're just missing the `_`?

Comment: Maybe can you make it not included in the form, and, just for a visual access `{{ form.vars.value.title }}` , [more info here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12497184/2454790) (it's twig exemple)

Comment: @Put12co22mer2 I think that's a good solution to display the value as a *static* text, can you please add an answer about this?

Comment: @geoB can you please provide a full example with the type of the field and the Symfony version?

Comment: @A.L I've added a use case, which I hope elucidates the issue.  It's always possible, even likely, that I'm making this more complex than it has to be.

Comment: I may have a solution that revolves around `'attr' => ['style' => 'display:none;']` in the event listener.  Details later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eventual solution: a service using Doctrine metadata to get disabled entity fields, form class modifications, and, for ManyToMany relationships, some jquery and invisible template entry.

Service functions:

```
/**
 * Create array of disabled fields of an entity object
 * 
 * @param type $object
 * @return array
 */
public function getDisabledOptions($object) {
    $values = [];
    $className = get_class($object);
    $metaData = $this->em->getClassMetadata($className);
    foreach ($metaData->associationMappings as $field => $mapping) {
        if (8 > $mapping['type']) {
            $fieldName = ucfirst($field);
            $method = 'get' . $fieldName;
            if (method_exists($object->$method(), 'getEnabled') && false === $object->$method()->getEnabled()) {
                $values[] = $fieldName;
            }
        }
    }
    $manyToMany = json_decode($this->getMetaData($object), true);
    foreach(array_keys($manyToMany) as $key) {
        $values[] = $key;
    }

    return $values;
}

/**
 * Get array of disabled ManyToMany options
 *
 * @param Object $object
 * @return array
 */
public function getMetaData($object) {
    $data = array();
    $className = get_class($object);
    $metaData = $this->em->getClassMetadata($className);
    foreach ($metaData->associationMappings as $field => $mapping) {
        if (8 === $mapping['type']) {
            $data[$field] = $this->extractOptions($object, $field);
        }
    }

    return json_encode($data);
}
```

Controller use of service:

```
    $searches = $this->get('mana.searches');
    $disabledOptions = $searches->getDisabledOptions($household);
    $metadata = $searches->getMetadata($household);
    ...
    $form = $this->createForm(HouseholdType::class, $household, $formOptions);
    ...
    return $this->render('Household/edit.html.twig',
            array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            ....
            'metadata' => $metadata,
    ));
```

Example of form class field:

```
        ->add('housing', EntityType::class,
            array(
            'class' => 'TruckeeProjectmanaBundle:Housing',
            'choice_label' => 'housing',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'attr' => (in_array('Housing', $options['disabledOptions']) ? ['disabled' => 'disabled'] : []),
            'label' => 'Housing: ',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
            if (false === in_array('Housing', $options['disabledOptions'])) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('alias')
                    ->orderBy('alias.housing', 'ASC')
                    ->where('alias.enabled=1');
            } else {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('alias')
                    ->orderBy('alias.housing', 'ASC');
            }
        },
        ))
        ...

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Truckee\ProjectmanaBundle\Entity\Household',
        'required' => false,
        'disabledOptions' => [],
    ));
}
```

Jquery to remove disabled attribute:

```
$("input[type=Submit]").click(function () {
    $("input").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("select").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Example of template & jquery for ManyToMany relationship:

```
<div id="household_options" style="display:none;">{{ metadata }}</div>
```

jquery:

```
if (0 < $("#household_options").length) {
    var house_options = JSON.parse($("#household_options").text());
    $.each(house_options, function (index, item) {
        $.each(item, function (k, v) {
            var formAttr = 'household_' + index + '_' + v.id;
            $("#" + formAttr).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    });
}
```